# node.js: implementing a stream which ignores 'end'

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I'm implementing some writable stream and use it like this:

```
const consumer = new MyStream() // stream which I implementing

// producer1 and producer2 are just instances of any Readable stream
producer1.pipe(consumer, {end: false})
producer2.pipe(consumer, {end: false})
```

The repetitive part here is `{end: false}`. Is there a way to configure the writable to ignore 'end' event from the producer?
process.stderr and process.stdout work like this

Comment: Are you implementing MyStream or the producer? If you're implementing MyStream then you're implementing a Duplex stream, not just a Writable stream.

Comment: added some comments to code. Shortly: i'm implementing MyStream()

How can implementing of duplex stream resolve can resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is not generated on demand, use [`write`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback), but add listener for [`drain`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain) event.

```
public writeStream(readableStream, cb) {
    if (!this.write(readableStream.read()) {
        this.once('drain', () => {
           console.log("Wait for drain event");
           cb();
        });
    else {
        process.nextTick(cb);
    }
    return this;
}
```